# how to ddl a table with an identity column

Tags: java, identity, ddl, jooq

I am trying to create a database table with `JOOQ` which contains an `id` which shall be `identity`.

For example my `SQL` generated by `JOOQ`is

```sql
create table "help"(
  "id" integer not null,
  "guid" varchar(36) not null,
  "category" nvarchar(255) null,
  "value" nvarchar(2048) null,
  constraint "PK_HELP_ID"
    primary key ("id"),
  constraint "UK_HELP_GUID"
    unique ("guid")
)
```

The `JOOQ` equivalent is:

```java
Name nameId = DSL.name("id");
Name nameGuid = DSL.name("guid");
Name nameCategory = DSL.name("category");
Name nameValue = DSL.name("value");
CreateTableConstraintStep table = create.createTable("help")//
        .column(nameId, SQLDataType.INTEGER.identity(true))//
        .column(nameGuid, SQLDataType.VARCHAR(36).nullable(false))//
        .column(nameCategory, SQLDataType.NVARCHAR(255))//
        .column(nameValue, SQLDataType.NVARCHAR(2048))//
        .constraints(//
                DSL.constraint("PK_HELP_ID").primaryKey(nameId),
                DSL.constraint("UK_HELP_GUID").unique(nameGuid));
```

i thought `SQLDataType.INTEGER.identity(true)` does exactly what i am searching for, but the result shows something different.

my investigation brought only these results:

1. The blog post about this on the `JOOQ`blog [identity columns - Subtle SQL differences: IDENTITY columns](https://blog.jooq.org/tag/identity-columns/)
2. And one issue on github [Add support for IDENTITY columns in CREATE TABLE statements #5062](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/5062)

**How do i declare an column as `identity` for `DDL` using `JOOQ`?**
JOOQ version 3.10.5

Comment: What `SQLDialect` are you using to generate the SQL?

Comment: i tried with SQL99, which is depricated and with DEFAULT. but obviously, as this stuff is database specific, as written in [1] ... this will result in what i got. *thanks* for pointing me on this one. using H2 or MySql gives the results i expected!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My mistake was to use `SQLDialect.SQL99` and `SQLDialect.DEFAULT`.

NOTE: `SQLDialect.SQL99` is deprecated.

obviously, as identity is database specific as pointed yout at reference [1](https://stackoverflow.com/users/521799/lukas-eder) from my question this will result in what i got. (as no identity is available for `DEFAULT` SQL.

```
DSLContext ctx = DSL.using(con, SQLDialect.DEFAULT);
```

If i configure my `DSLContext` with `SQLDialect.H2` or for example `SQLDialect.MYSQL` `JOOQ` generates the correct output.

```
DSLContext ctx = DSL.using(con, SQLDialect.H2);
```

Thanks to [Lukas Eder](https://stackoverflow.com/users/521799/lukas-eder) for pointing out my mistake.